# SQL Query to count the records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am making up a SQL query which will get all the transaction types from one table, and from the other table it will count the frequency of that transaction type.

My query is this:

```
with CTE as
(
select a.trxType,a.created,b.transaction_key,b.description,a.mode
FROM transaction_data AS a with (nolock)
     RIGHT JOIN transaction_types b with (nolock) ON b.transaction_key = a.trxType 
 )
SELECT COUNT (trxType) AS Frequency, description as trxType,mode
from CTE where created >='2017-04-11' and created <= '2018-04-13'
group by trxType ,description,mode
```

The `transaction_types` table contains all the types of transactions only and `transaction_data` contains the transactions which have occurred.

The problem I am facing is that even though it's the `RIGHT join`, it does not select all the records from the `transaction_types` table.

I need to select all the transactions from the `transaction_types` table and show the number of counts for each transaction, even if it's 0.

Please help.

Comment: Remove trxType from GROUP BY. You typically group by the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is so much easier to follow.

I think you want:

```
select tt.transaction_key, tt.description, t.mode, count(t.trxType)
from transaction_types tt left join
     transaction_data t
     on tt.transaction_key = t.trxType and
        t.created >= '2017-04-11' and t.created <= '2018-04-13'
group by tt.transaction_key, tt.description, t.mode;
```

Notes:

- Use reasonable table aliases!  `a` and `b` mean nothing.  `t` and `tt` are abbreviations of the table name, so they are easier to follow.
- `t.mode` will be `NULL` for non-matching rows.
- The condition on dates needs to be in the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, the outer join is turned into an inner join.
- `LEFT JOIN` is easier to follow (at least for people whose native language reads left-to-right) because it means "keep all the rows in the table you have already read".

Comment: is there a way I can select t.mode for all transaction types ?

Comment: can you please put some light on it ?

Comment: @Talib . . . No, you cannot select the value for non-matching rows.